# How can an interface expose a public property/method that does not exist in the implementing class?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, interface

Question in short:
public class DbContext : IDisposable, IObjectContextAdapter

DbContext implements IObjectContextAdapter. IObjectContextAdapter has a single property,

```
public interface IObjectContextAdapter
{
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the object context.
    ObjectContext ObjectContext { get; }
}
```

however, I cannot find this property in DbContext; it simple is not there in metadata code. Only way to access it, is to cast DbContext as IObjectContextAdapter.

I do not understand - I would've thought that public properties of an interface are exposed by the implementing classes regardless of being cast into the interface or not. I feel like I'm missing something big here...

Comment: An implementing class must implment all members of the interface, otherwise its not an implememnter.

Comment: Doh, I just found the answer - explicit interface implementation for private properties only exposed in interfaces? Learn sth new every day !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that `DbContext` implemented that property *explicitly*, like so:

```
public class DbContext : IObjectContextAdapter
{
    ObjectContext IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext { get { ... }}
}
```

When a member is implemented explicitly, the instance will have to be casted to its interface in order to be accessible.

This *technique* is usually useful for implementing two members with the same signature. For example, when implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, you must implement two members:

- `IEnumerator GetEnumerator` from `IEnumerable`
- `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator` from `IEnumerable<T>`

One of them will *have* to be implemented explicitly:

```
public class X : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Some classes in the .NET framework use this to *hide* or discourage the usage of certain members. [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) discourages the usage of `IProducerConsumerCollection.TryAdd` and encourages the usage of `ConcurrentQueue<T>.Enqueue` instead.

See: [MSDN Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is an explicit interface implmentation, see below

```
interface IExplicit
{
    void Explicit();
}

class Something : IExplicit
{
    void IExplicit.Explicit()
    {
    }
}
```

so, we can instantiate a `new Something()`, but to access the `IExplicit` implementation we have to cast the type.

```
var something = new Something();

// Compile time error.
something.Explicit();

// But we can do.
((IExplicit)something).Explicit();
```